# How would I execute a .jar using terminal, permissions only does Read and write, yet not execute

Tags: command-line, permissions, lubuntu, java

The file I am trying to execute is TechnicLauncher(1).jar
I have tried looking in the permissions (as mentioned before) but it does not show where it can be executed. I have also tried looking in preferences but same thing.
I am running Lubuntu with xfce.

How will I execute it using the terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this to run java application from CLI?

`java -jar application.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Linux can run foreign binary, like a JAR file. This is how Wine works, for example. To run JAR files as executable do the following in a console

```
sudo apt-get install binfmt-support
```

Cd to your JAR file and change it to executable (you can also do this through file properties in Nautilus)

```
chmod a+x myjar.jar
```

You can then run your jar file using a terminal, just like it was any other binary executable or shell script.

```
./myjar.jar
```